# Dagger2: Mark external type as singleton

Tags: java, dagger-2

I am depending on an external type (that I don't control) with several constructor args. The constructor is marked with `@Inject`, but I want to have dagger treat the type as `@Singleton`.

Is there a way to do this without copying all the constructor args into a `@Provides`-annotated function?

```
@Module
interface MyModule {

    /** Is this the only way? */
    @Provides @Singleton
    static ExternalType makeSingleton(
        ExternalDepA a, ExternalDepB b, ExternalDepC c,
        ExternalDepD d, ExternalDepE e, ExternalDepF f) {

        return new ExternalType(a, b, c, d, e, f);
    }
}
```

---

**Update**: The following doesn't work either; first, `@Binds` is for interface-to-implementation binding (as @YavorMitev also points out in the comments); second it produces a circular dependency error.

```
@Module
interface ThisDoesNotWork {

    /**  BAD */
    @Binds @Singleton ExternalType makeSingleton(ExternalType external);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this. Binds is used when you have an interface and implementation of that interface. Also you can fix the Circ Dep by using Lazy<>, but not the Kotlin one, but the Dagger one.

Comment: @YavorMitev That's why it is marked as bad. The first code snippet does what I want to do, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Put Inject and Singleton where the constructor of ExternalType is and delete the above code.

Comment: @YavorMitev Its an *external type* that I don't control. Hence the question. I've updated the question with hopefully more clarity.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. No - this is the only way :) And this is a good thing in my opinion. Otherwise, you will be splitting the declaration. "Go for Injection dependncy info there, but here you will find the scope." It will be confusing.